# Programmatically publish a post (custom post type) with custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type 'Participant' with many custom fields. I also have a form with corresponding input fields for the user to fill out. When he submits the form, I want a new post to be generated with each custom fields containing the value chosen by the user.

Is it possible to do and if so, how?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use [wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) and [add_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta), like this:

```
// insert the post and set the category
$post_id = wp_insert_post(array (
    'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
    'post_title' => $your_title,
    'post_content' => $your_content,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'comment_status' => 'closed',   // if you prefer
    'ping_status' => 'closed',      // if you prefer
));

if ($post_id) {
    // insert post meta
    add_post_meta($post_id, '_your_custom_1', $custom1);
    add_post_meta($post_id, '_your_custom_2', $custom2);
    add_post_meta($post_id, '_your_custom_3', $custom3);
}
```

Comment: Works as charm even on WordPress 4.4.2 :) !

Comment: nowadays, you can simply add meta fileds via the meta_input key in wp_insert_post: `'meta_input' => ['_your_custom_1' => $custom1, '_your_custom_2' => custom2]`

Comment: Good point @Andreas, I suggest that you add that as a new answer and let it start getting up votes. It should be the answer now.

Comment: Thx @webaware :)

Comment: Works as charm even on WordPress 5.1 :) !

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the [great answer of @webaware](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77205/146132) above, this can be handled since [wordpress 4.4.0](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/since/4.4.0/) all via the [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) call:

```php
$post_id = wp_insert_post(array (
    'post_content' => $content,
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type',
    'post_status' => 'publish',

    // some simple key / value array
    'meta_input' => array(
        'your_custom_key1' => 'your_custom_value1',
        'your_custom_key2' => 'your_custom_value2'
        // and so on ;)
    )
));

if ($post_id) {
    // it worked :)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved quite easily using the [Gravity Forms plugin](http://www.gravityforms.com/). You can build a form which populates a Custom Post Type in the backend. This post can be set to appear as a draft or as published. No problem adding custom fields. In my case, I used it to gather client testimonials.

Comment: I like this solution, especially if you're delivering it to a client that wants to manage the form themselves.